# how to limit dependency injections in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I used dependency injections in my controllers as follows.

```
 .controller('deals_list', function ($scope, global, config, services, dealService, pagination) {
```

Now the app was growed. Dependencies are growing too. I want limit these injections. So is there a way to limit those with global injections or something?

What kind of procedure actually should I follow?

Comment: do you use all those services in that controller? if so, then they need to be injected. I find it unlikely that every controller has to use a `global` service, `config` service, and whatever the `services` service might be....

Comment: I have several controllers for CRUDs. So I have to inject all services in each controllers.

Comment: maybe you can group them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $http, $timeout, YourService) {
    $rootScope.MyService = YourService;
}
```

Used it into controller :

```
myApp.controller('YouCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
    // scope inherits from root scope
    $scope.MyService.doSomething();
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What i believe you can do is to create a service that contains all the services that you want to use. The global service is like a facade into your real service.

The option then are to create on global service with all dependencies included. Or multiple facade service which group these services

```
app.service("Configurations",function(global,config) {
  this.global=global;
  this.standard=config;
});

app.service("AppServices",function(services, dealService, pagination) {
  this.services=services;
  // other assigments
});
```

Now you can inject `Configurations` and `AppServices`

This at least gives some visibility into what your controllers are dependent upon.